# Is it possible to have the google closure compiler minify libraries?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I'm looking for a way to allow the closure compiler to minify external libraries. I'm very familiar with how externs work and this is **not** what i'm looking for at all. Instead, I **want** closure to compile these libraries alongside my code to produce 1 file.

Most of these libraries will use `require` for imports (like [flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux)).

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Background:

- I'm using closure-library for my entire application (up until now).
- I've read the FAQ [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/JS-Modules) about Js-Modules which seems to suggest I just use the `require` syntax. But, I would rather not include the `commonjs` library just so I can use `require`.
- I'm not using `gulp`/`browserify`/`es6`/etc. Instead I am only using the `closure-compiler` (along with stylesheets etc) to produce a `app.js` file for the browser.

Comment: We're really really close to being able to make this a reality. I'm actively working on it. But for today, the answer is "not very well".

Comment: Since Closure does a really good job for stripping unused code this would be a great feature! Its a bummer when you have to use an entire library when only half is necessary